# How can i export an arima model in R ? So that, another application can use this model to forecast time series

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, microservices, forecasting

I am working on microservices application. So i have to write R and Python scripts. My R script is required to create arima models. After that my Python scripts are required to use the created arima models to forecast time series.

In my R script, i achieved to create models and compare them. But, i don't know how to export them to make python scripts use models.

I tried **pmml::savePMML(arimaModel1)** function to create pmml file.

But i received this **ERROR :**

*Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'saveXML' for signature '"list"'*

I think this error is caused by object type differences.

Is there a way to export my created arima models, so that my python scripts use them to predict time series ?

**My R Script:**

```
if (!require("xts")) {
  # install.packages("xts", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/") # for r terminal, docker
  install.packages("xts") 
  library("xts")
}
if (!require("astsa")) {
  # install.packages("astsa", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/") # for r terminal, docker
  install.packages("astsa") 
  library("astsa")
}

if (!require("forecast")) {
  # install.packages("forecast", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/") # for r terminal, docker
  install.packages("forecast") 
  library("forecast")
}

elecTurkeyData <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) # original data

head(elecTurkeyData)
tail(elecTurkeyData)
date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(elecTurkeyData$Date..Montly.)), format="%d-%m-%Y")
consumption <- as.numeric(elecTurkeyData$T.C..Elektricity.consumption..Gross.Demand..Kwh) # original data

tcElektricityConsumption <- data.frame(Date=date,
                                       consumption=consumption, 
                                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
plot(tcElektricityConsumption, main = "TC Electiricity Consumption", type= "o") # buggy plot
xtsTcElektricityConsumption <- xts(tcElektricityConsumption[, -1], order.by=date)
periodicity(xtsTcElektricityConsumption)
plot.xts(xtsTcElektricityConsumption, main = "TC Electiricity Consumption")
plot(diff(xtsTcElektricityConsumption), main = "Diff TC Electiricity Consumption")
plot(log(xtsTcElektricityConsumption), main = "Log TC Electiricity Consumption")
plot(diff(log(xtsTcElektricityConsumption)), main = "Diff Log TC Electiricity Consumption")


timeseries <- ts(data=xtsTcElektricityConsumption, frequency=12)

arimaModel1 <- sarima(log(timeseries), p = 0, d = 1, q = 1, P = 0, D = 1, Q = 0, S = 12) # dataiku model, AIC = -5.649985
arimaModel2 <- sarima(log(timeseries), p = 1, d = 1, q=1, P = 0, D = 1, Q = 1, S = 12) # AIC = -5.804879
arimaModel3 <- sarima(log(timeseries), 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 12) # AIC = -5.810673
arimaModel4 <- sarima(log(timeseries), p = 3, d = 0, q=1, P = 0, D = 1, Q = 2, S = 12) # AIC = -5.836181
arimaModel5 <- sarima(log(timeseries), p = 3, d = 0, q=1, P = 1, D = 1, Q = 1, S = 12) # AIC = -5.844795


barplot(c(ARIMA1=arimaModel1$AIC, ARIMA2=arimaModel2$AIC, ARIMA3=arimaModel3$AIC, ARIMA4=arimaModel4$AIC, ARIMA5=arimaModel5$AIC),
        col='light blue',
        ylab='AIC')
```

Comment: why cant you just create the models in python?

Comment: Is there a way to create arima models and export them as pmml files in Python ? Simply, I know how to use R to analyze time series and python to data manipulation, client server communication and so on. However, if python is more suitable for creating arima pmml files easily, i will use python.

Comment: it is more suitable if you are deploying your models in python.

Comment: One of the most important thing for the project is to create pmml or pmml like files and saving them in database. Which python libraries do you suggest me to create arima models and save them as pmml files ?

Comment: you can try https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml

Comment: Thank you. I will check this.